# NodeJS JSON parsing and re-parsing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

ok so basically I have the first part of json parsing down,

I am more having problems reparsing what was parsed and making a new VAR

my first var parse "balance = data[1];" returns the following:

```
Order66 has MdjToSjG4UnJGzTgxWebFjvdH75M4mUemB,138.94745346,Order66 in their account.
```

the

> MdjToSjG4UnJGzTgxWebFjvdH75M4mUemB,138.94745346,Order66

is the parse in variable.

now what I need to do is re-parse that so it only shows me the

> 138.94745346

I've looked on google quite a bit before asking here.... nothing seems to work correctly :/

Comment: Is it just me or are you using the terminology 'parsing' incorrectly. So basically you have a string.. and you want the section in that string after the first comma and want it to end at the next comma.

Comment: Are you sure the `"MdjToSjG4UnJGzTgxWebFjvdH75M4mUemB,138.94745346,Order66"` is a single string, and not an array of three elements that got coerced to a string because you concatenated it with some strings to form a message? If it *is* a single string, the fact that it came from a property of an object that came from JSON isn't relevant, is it? If you think it is relevant, please [edit] show a sample of the original JSON string, and the JavaScript code that parsed it. Actually, it wouldn't hurt to show the JSON either way...

Answer (score 1):

You could "parse" the variable by using [`split()`-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like this:

```
"MdjToSjG4UnJGzTgxWebFjvdH75M4mUemB,138.94745346,Order66".split(',')[1]
```

Which should have the output you need: `138.94745346`.

This is how you would use it with your code:

```
var balanceString = data[1].split(',')[1];
```

The result of split will be a string, so if you need the amount as a float, you will need to use the [`parseFloat()`-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
var balance = parseFloat(balanceString);
```